# trace inequality of submatrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, inverse

I got stuck on this problem. Suppose $Y_{k\times d}$ is a matrix, and $Y_1$ is the submatrix of $Y$ consisting of the first $m-$rows of $Y$. I am wondering wether the following inequality is true?

$$tr(Y_1^\mathrm{T}Y_1(Y^\mathrm{T}Y)^{-1})\ge \frac{tr(Y_1^\mathrm{T}Y_1)}{tr(Y^\mathrm{T}Y)}$$
I have done a lot of numerical experiments in matlab, and did not find any counter-example, but I do not know how to prove it.

Moreover, what I really want to know is that is there any equality holds between the LHS and RHS or if there is a constant $C$ such that

$$tr(Y_1^\mathrm{T}Y_1(Y^\mathrm{T}Y)^{-1})\le C\frac{tr(Y_1^\mathrm{T}Y_1)}{tr(Y^\mathrm{T}Y)}$$.

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We have $B:=Y^TY\succeq A:=Y_1^TY_1\succeq0$. Your first inequality is equivalent to $\operatorname{tr}(AB^{-1})\ge\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A)}{\operatorname{tr}(B)}$, which follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\langle A^{1/2}B^{-1/2},A^{1/2}B^{-1/2}\rangle
\langle B^{1/2},B^{1/2}\rangle
\ge\langle B^{1/2},B^{-1/2}A^{1/2}\rangle^2
$$
where $\langle X,Y\rangle$ denotes the Frobenius inner product $\operatorname{tr}(X^TY)$.

The desired constant $C$ in your second inequality does not exist. Intuitively, that's because $B^{1/2}$ can be almost orthogonal to $B^{-1/2}A^{1/2}$. For instance, let
$$
Y=\pmatrix{t&0\\ 0&t\\ 0&1},\,Y_1=\pmatrix{t&0\\ 0&t},\,Y^TY=\pmatrix{t^2&0\\ 0&t^2+1},\,Y_1^TY_1=\pmatrix{t^2&0\\ 0&t^2}
$$
for some nonzero $t$. Then
$$
\operatorname{tr}\left(Y_1^TY_1(Y^TY)^{-1}\right)=1+\frac{t^2}{t^2+1},
\quad\frac{\operatorname{tr}(Y_1^TY_1)}{\operatorname{tr}(Y^TY)}=\frac{2t^2}{2t^2+1}.
$$
Clearly, there does not exist any constant $C$ such that
$1+\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}\le\frac{Ct^2}{1+t^2}$ for all $t$, because $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\left(1+\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}\right)=1>0=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{2Ct^2}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In the second part, I have to applogise for my mistake on posting the problem. $_1$ is the first $d−rows$ of $$, so $_1$ is a $d\times d$ square matrix. Do you have any insights about what would happen if $_1$ is a invertiable matrix

Comment: @MaohuiLyu Please see my new edit.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much for this details.